# MFC , C++ in embedded(semiconductor) projects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

What are the internal features/aspects  of C++/ VC++ and MFC that are used for embedded(semiconductor) projects by large IT companies. I ask this becuase I need to be prepared for one such poistion.

please reply.

Comment: To be prepared for an embedded systems position, you will need to know C, assembly language, some electronics and sometimes mechanical engineering (and physics).  You may want to target smaller companies that produce products rather than big IT shops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC isn't used in typical embedded projects. It's an old Microsoft library, typically used for PC software as opposed to embedded software. C++ (the language) and VC++ (a Microsoft compiler for the C++ language) are used in embedded projects. However, the Microsoft compiler cannot target common embedded platforms such as ARM-linux. You'd find that GCC is more commonly used as the C++ compiler for embedded ARM-linux platforms.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the specific features of C++ that are typically used for such projects

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 and later can target the ARM processor.  For older projects there is Visual Embedded C++.  And although GCC is commonly used, there are other alternatives such as Green Hills and Metaware.

Comment: I'll +1 even though the "old" is not fair. MFC is recently updated and its age is not what makes it inappropriate for embedded.